# Get certain row from modulus (php)

Tags: php, mysql, modulus

I have a table with time entries of taxi rides. I need to list date of rides and every nth ride needs to be free. Thats what i managed to do with this code which shows all rides in table and every 5th is free, counting from first entry:

```
$c = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<table>";
$i=$c;
while ($re = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $time = $re["time"];
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "<td>$time</td>";
    if ($i != 0 && $i%5 == 0)
        echo "<td>Free ride</td>";
    $i--;
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Now i need to echo 'Next ride is free' notification when its one ride before free one and echo 'This ride is free' when ride is free.
How I can get that one ride from modulus, free one and ride before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the row before every fifth row, the result of the modulo operation will be `4`.. You need to check this in an additional `if` statement:

```
if ($i%5 == 4) {
    echo "the next ride is free";
}
```